# I need to call another sql file within an sql file using sql plus

Tags: sql, sql-server, unix, plsql, sqlplus

I need to call another sql file within an sql file using sql plus. This si the script i have so far and its not working. I have to code it in a unix vi file.  I am new to this so would someone mind helping. thank you in advance.

```
 call=`$LIVE_SQL/sqlfile2.sql`
 if  &call = 0  then
   echo "ERROR: $LIVE_SQL/sqlfile2.sql file not found"
   exit 1
 fi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command to call other SQL files from within SQLPLUS is : start (or @)

Getting feedback from the SQL script : SQLPLUS is not Bash. It is possible, but not really beginner stuff.