# How to call .sql files trough another .sql file in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, file

I have 25 sql files that comes from a `mysqldump` each one. Lets says they call db1.sql, db2.sql ... and so on.

I want to create a sql file to call all the others. Lets says this file will cal rumTest.sql .

Inside runTest.sql I wrote:

```
\. C:\pathToFIle\db1.sql;
\. C:\pathToFIle\db2.sql;
\. C:\pathToFIle\db3.sql;
...
```

So, inside my command window I call the file as

```
\. C:\pathToFIle\rumTest.sql;
```

This is not working. I've tried in different ways to put double cotes when calling  `"\. C:\pathToFIle\db1.sql;"` inside rumTest.sql.

I see that Mysql reads what is inside rumTest.sql but not execute the command to read db1.sql, for example.
So, what could be the best approach to perform this task?
I fond these 2 posts but they are related to oracle [I need to call another sql file within an sql file using sql plus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27103525/i-need-to-call-another-sql-file-within-an-sql-file-using-sql-plus)

Comment: Have you tried quoting just the file name, not the whole command?
    \. "C:\pathToFIle\db1.sql";

Comment: Hi Eresov. I've tried all possibilities of quoting.

Comment: Try escaping the backslashes:

    source c:\\pathtofile\\db1.sql;

you can also try '/' as a path separator

    source c:/pathtofile/db1.sql;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution - that works (tested).

We do not need to use ";" at the end.
So the file should look like this:

```
//File rumTest.sql 

\. C:\pathToFIle\db1.sql
\. C:\pathToFIle\db2.sql
\. C:\pathToFIle\db3.sql
```

But if we want to insert some sql command we should use ";" for each line.
The code should looks like this:

```
//File rumTest.sql    

\. C:\pathToFIle\db1.sql
USE db1;
SHOW TABLES;
\. C:\pathToFIle\db2.sql
SHOW TABLES; //(Display db2 tables. db2 is already selected)
\. C:\pathToFIle\db3.sql
```

So in your cmd window You only call

```
\. C:\pathToFIle\rumTest.sql
```

then the file will call all others.

Comment: You have to note the source command (alias \.) is not a SQL command but a mySQL command.
The naming of the main script should not have the extension `.sql` as it is more a batch commands for mySQL and this lead to confusion as such sql file would not be executable from a classic SQL editor such as MySQL-Workbench.

Answer (score 1):

Inside your main sql file, you can place the other sql file like below:

Inside Main file (C:\main.sql)

`SET @NAME = 'XYZ';`

`SOURCE C:\abc.sql`

To execute this C:\main.sql:

`mysql -h abc -u xyz -p mno < C:\main.sql`

inside C:\abc.sql

`use table1;`

`insert into table1.school(name)values(concat('RAM_',@NAME));`

All occurences of NAME in file C:\abc.sql would be replaced by XYZ.

output:
`insert into table1.school(name)values(RAM_XYZ);`

This would work.You may try!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the `source` command in your script:

```
source C:\pathToFIle\db1.sql;
source C:\pathToFIle\db2.sql;
source C:\pathToFIle\db3.sql;
...
```

and call the script like:

```
mysql -u YourUsername -p < C:\pathToFIle\rumTest.sql
```

Comment: Hi Bran, It will not change. The script is to create a db.

Comment: Edited based on your comment.  What error messages are displayed when you run your scripts?

Comment: You have to note the source command is not a SQL command but a mySQL command.
The naming of the main script should not have the extension .sql as it is more a batch commands for mySQL and this lead to confusion as such sql file would not be executable from a classic SQL editor such as MySQL-Workbench.